# How to display 3 months one by one in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

How can I display 90 days in a full Calendar. Please look at the following fiddle.

1) In this fiddle, By default it is displaying one month and next month's 12 days. I want same as display 3 months continously.

How can I do this using full Calendar.

My requirement is,

i) I have start and end date is there on top. ( Please see the fiddle).

ii) If I select 3 months in a calendar, I want to display 3 months data in a fullCalendar.

iii) If I select one month, I just want t show only one month. Same as 2 months also.

If the whole month is empty means, i don't want to show that whole month. If atleast one data is there in a month, I want to show that month in full Calendar.

Please help me how can I do this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jyxs6Lc/3/)

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
 },
 defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
 editable: true,
});
$("td.fc-day.fc-widget-content").each(function( index ) {
    var start = moment('2014-06-04'); //start date from start date input
        var end = moment('2014-06-18'); //end date from end date input
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        var date = $(this).data('date'); //get current date in loop
        var day = moment(date); //create a moment
        
        //if day is greater than start date and less than end date, display.
        if(day > start && day < end) {
         $(this).append("<span style='font-size: 30px;font-weight: 600;color: green;'>"+random+"%</span>");
        }
    });
```

```css
body {
 margin-top: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

#calendar {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
Start Date :<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value=""> 
End date :<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value=""></br></br></br></br>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```